# Stream processor shutdown GCP

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka

Here we are working on Kafka Stream process which is running at a VM in GCP.
The thing is that I have autoscaled Kafka Stream processor but since this it is autoscaled now and everything is working as it was suppose to be but we have notice that once the traffic gets low, all new VM's which get spin goes down.

what we want is before it get shutdown or get terminate the VM in autoscale group should check whether if some query  or process are in pendng or in-process state then after checking the autoscale group, it should wait for that VM until all the process is completed and when that process is completed, then only should delete the virtual machine.

So far i haven't figured out how to do what i want, so no implementation has been done

Answer (score 1):

> what we want is before it get shutdown or get terminate the VM in
> autoscale group should check whether if some query or process are in
> pendng or in-process state then after checking the autoscale group, it
> should wait for that VM until all the process is completed and when
> that process is completed, then only should delete the virtual
> machine.

[Autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler) decides the scaling up/down instances in Managed Instances Group (MIG).

To achieve your requirement, you can create a custom [cloud monitoring metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/ops-agent/third-party/kafka) based on your application usage.

From [GCP documentation:](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-cloud-monitoring-metrics)

> Autoscaling based on Cloud Monitoring metrics lets you adjust the
> capacity needed according to measurements from your app. When you
> autoscale a MIG based on a metric, the autoscaler creates VMs when the
> metric value increases and deletes VMs when the value decreases.
>
> For example, you can define how many VMs you need per user count,
> latency, or the number of messages in a Pub/Sub subscription.